# Adding MediaItem when using the media3 library caused an error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I am using the latest Android Media3 library, but I found a problem in using it...

I created a **MediaSessionService**, and then got the MediaController in the **Activity**, and then when I tried to call the media controller and add some MediaItems, an error occurred:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at androidx.media3.common.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:155)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.DefaultMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(DefaultMediaSourceFactory.java:338)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImpl.createMediaSources(ExoPlayerImpl.java:1164)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImpl.addMediaItems(ExoPlayerImpl.java:463)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.SimpleExoPlayer.addMediaItems(SimpleExoPlayer.java:1146)
        at androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer.addMediaItems(BasePlayer.java:69)
        at androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer.addMediaItem(BasePlayer.java:64)
        at androidx.media3.common.ForwardingPlayer.addMediaItem(ForwardingPlayer.java:90)
        at androidx.media3.session.PlayerWrapper.addMediaItem(PlayerWrapper.java:346)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.lambda$addMediaItem$28(MediaSessionStub.java:1052)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.lambda$getSessionTaskWithPlayerCommandRunnable$2$androidx-media3-session-MediaSessionStub(MediaSessionStub.java:234)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub$$ExternalSyntheticLambda52.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.lambda$flushCommandQueue$50(MediaSessionStub.java:1479)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub$$ExternalSyntheticLambda58.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.media3.common.util.Util.postOrRun(Util.java:517)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.flushCommandQueue(MediaSessionStub.java:1473)
        at androidx.media3.session.MediaControllerImplBase$FlushCommandQueueHandler.handleMessage(MediaControllerImplBase.java:3035)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7813)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

So I checked the createMediaSource function of DefaultMediaSourceFactory and found that it is checking whether the `localConfiguration` of MediaItem is null:

```
  @Override
  public MediaSource createMediaSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    checkNotNull(mediaItem.localConfiguration);
    ...
  }
```

And this is localConfiguration:

```
/**
   * Optional configuration for local playback. May be {@code null} if shared over process
   * boundaries.
   */
  @Nullable public final LocalConfiguration localConfiguration;
```

I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the way I created the MediaItem, and it works well inside the Service, but when I try to insert the MediaItem in the Activity, an error occurs. According to the comments, I guess this may be a cross-process communication problem, but I don't have any clue about this. Does anyone have experience with Media3?

Comment: Im currently having exactly the same issue...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you add/set MediaItems from a controller, the `localConfiguration` (uri, mimeType, drm config, etc) of MediaItem is removed for [security/privacy reasons](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/43#issuecomment-1055836630). Without `localConfiguration` the player can't play the media item. We need to add the missing information back to the MediaItem.

### Updated answer (media3 1.0.0-beta01 or higher)

Open the Callback you defined when creating the MediaLibrarySession in your Service.

```kotlin
// My MediaLibraryService
// onCreate()
mediaLibrarySession = MediaLibrarySession.Builder(
    this, 
    player, 
    librarySessionCallback // <--
).build()


// NOTE: If you are using MediaSessionService instead of MediaLibraryService,
// use `setCallback(librarySessionCallback)` from the MediaSession.Builder.
```

Override `onAddMediaItems` inside your `MediaLibrarySession.Callback`. Every time you use `setMediaItem`/`addMediaItem` from a controller, your [onAddMediaItems will be called](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/1.0.0-beta01/libraries/session/src/main/java/androidx/media3/session/MediaSession.java#L972) and the MediaItems returned there are the ones that will be played.

```kotlin
class CustomMediaLibrarySessionCallback : MediaLibraryService.MediaLibrarySession.Callback {

    // [...]

    override fun onAddMediaItems(
        mediaSession: MediaSession,
        controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
        mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>
    ): ListenableFuture<List<MediaItem>> {
        // NOTE: You can use the id from the mediaItems to look up missing 
        // information (e.g. get URI from a database) and return a Future with 
        // a list of playable MediaItems.

        // If your use case is really simple and the security/privacy reasons 
        // mentioned earlier don't apply to you, you can add the URI to the 
        // MediaItem request metadata in your activity/fragment and use it
        // to rebuild the playable MediaItem.
        val updatedMediaItems = mediaItems.map { mediaItem ->
            mediaItem.buildUpon()
                .setUri(mediaItem.requestMetadata.mediaUri)
                .build()
        }
        return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
    }
}
```

Create and play your `MediaItem` from the activity/fragment.

```kotlin
// My Activity

val mmd = MediaMetadata.Builder()
    .setTitle("Example")
    .setArtist("Artist name")
    .build()

// Request metadata. New in (1.0.0-beta01)
// This is optional. I'm adding a RequestMetadata to the MediaItem so I 
// can get the mediaUri from my `onAddMediaItems` simple use case (see  
// onAddMediaItems for more info).
// If you are going to get the final URI from a database, you can move your 
// query to your `MediaLibrarySession.Callback#onAddMediaItems` and skip this.
val rmd = RequestMetadata.Builder()
    .setMediaUri("...".toUri())
    .build()

val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
    .setMediaId("123")
    .setMediaMetadata(mmd)
    .setRequestMetadata(rmd)
    .build()

browser.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
browser.prepare()
browser.play()
```

---

### Old answer (media3 1.0.0-alpha)

When you create the `MediaLibrarySession` inside your `MediaLibraryService`, you can add a `MediaItemFiller`. This `MediaItemFiller` has a `fillInLocalConfiguration` method that will be ["Called to fill in the MediaItem.localConfiguration of the media item from controllers."](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/72a4fb082d9e68ecd7db3ff87b19f4232a5991d2/libraries/session/src/main/java/androidx/media3/session/MediaSession.java#L1001)

Knowing this, you need to:

Add a MediaItemFiller to your MediaLibrarySession builder inside your service.

```kotlin
// My MediaLibraryService
// onCreate()
mediaLibrarySession = MediaLibrarySession.Builder(this, player, librarySessionCallback)
    .setMediaItemFiller(CustomMediaItemFiller()) // <--
    .setSessionActivity(pendingIntent)
    .build()
```

Create a custom `MediaSession.MediaItemFiller`. Any time you use a `setMediaItem`/`addMediaItem` from a controller this will be called and the MediaItem returned here will be the one played.

```kotlin
class CustomMediaItemFiller : MediaSession.MediaItemFiller {
  override fun fillInLocalConfiguration(
    session: MediaSession,
    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
    mediaItem: MediaItem
  ): MediaItem {
    // Return the media item to be played
    return mediaItem.buildUpon()
        // Use the metadata values to fill our media item
        .setUri(mediaItem.mediaMetadata.mediaUri)
        .build()
  }
}
```

And finally, create and play your `MediaItem` from the activity.

```kotlin
// My Activity

// Fill some metadata that the MediaItemFiller 
// will use to create the new MediaItem
val mmd = MediaMetadata.Builder()
    .setTitle("Example")
    .setArtist("Artist name")
    .setMediaUri("...".toUri())
    .build()

val mediaItem: MediaItem =
    MediaItem.Builder()
        .setMediaMetadata(mmd)
        .build()

browser.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
browser.prepare()
browser.play()
```

I don't know why it has to be this awkward, but if you have a look to the [CustomMediaItemFiller they use in the official repo](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/039eef00bf9de7f03f65c481e41a1f0437a12d27/demos/session/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/session/PlaybackService.kt#L129), you will see that they use the `mediaItem.mediaId` to fetch a valid MediaItem from a media catalog. That's why their demo works when they use [setMediaItem from an activity](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/039eef00bf9de7f03f65c481e41a1f0437a12d27/demos/session/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/session/PlayableFolderActivity.kt#L70).

Also, as far as I know, anything you do inside `fillInLocalConfiguration` has to block the main thread (I believe `setMediaItem` has to be called from main) so, if you can, try to move any heavy work (ie, get media info from your database) to your Activity/ViewModel where you have more control, fill all the metadata you need there, and use your `MediaSession.MediaItemFiller` to do a simple transformation. Or move everything to your service and forget about everything.

I hope the flow is understood. I don't have much experience with media3 and maybe I'm missing something, but with the limitations of `MediaItemFiller` I found it a bit useless and I would really like to know more about its purpose.

Comment: Hey @spun thanks for the solution. I am trying the code that you have suggested but the controller is always `null` and I have no idea where to set it. Would you look at [my code](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/jufesasexa.kotlin) please?

Comment: Hi @ilkeraslan, I think the problem is that you are creating the `MediaItem` and playing it just after calling `initializeController` and the initialization is asynchronous so the controller is not ready. When you use `controllerFuture.addListener({ setController() }, /*...*/)` is like saying "call `setController()` when the controller is ready" so that's the only place where you can be sure that the controller can be used. Move your `MediaItem` creation and your controller calls from `onStart` to `setController` and try again. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @spun, it was a great pointer to the solution. The only problem with moving the `setController()` to `onStart()` is that if you minimize the app and re-click it the controller is set again causing the media item to be reproduced. Thus I preferred to call the `setController()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: My service class is extending from `MediaSessionService`. The Builder for `MediaSession` doesn't have `setMediaItemFiller` method.

Comment: Hi @Rafsanjani, you are right, in `version 1.0.0-alpha01` the `setMediaItemFiller` in `MediaSession.Builder` was not public. This was fixed [a couple of months ago](https://github.com/androidx/media/commit/2a62a5ee302d694eb9c7099024d13607f6143830). 
If you can't wait until the next release, you could try [running the library locally](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/main/README.md#locally)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trick!
Media3 seems to help reducing extra boilerplate, but it doesn't seem to be well documented and not much samples available around it.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in media3 1.1.0 and should work without any additional workarounds:

https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/282#issuecomment-1645323234