# Android Media3 Session & Controller - Playback not starting

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession

I'm trying to implement the Android [Media3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3) MediaSessionService and MediaController but for some reason the playback doesn't start. What am I doing wrong? I think I did everything exactly as described in [Play media in the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/playing-in-background).

PlaybackService.kt

```
class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService() {

    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player).build()
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? =
        mediaSession

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var controllerFuture: ListenableFuture<MediaController>
    private lateinit var controller: MediaController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        log("onCreate MainActivity")
        setContent {
            TestMediaTheme {

                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                    Button(onClick = {

                        //val url = "android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.test}"
                        val url = "https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3"

                        play(url)

                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Play")
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, PlaybackService::class.java))
        controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken).buildAsync()
        controllerFuture.addListener(
            {
                controller = controllerFuture.get()
                initController()
            },
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
        )
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        MediaController.releaseFuture(controllerFuture)
        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun initController() {
        //controller.playWhenReady = true
        controller.addListener(object : Player.Listener {

            override fun onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata: MediaMetadata) {
                super.onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata)
                log("onMediaMetadataChanged=$mediaMetadata")
            }

            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                log("onIsPlayingChanged=$isPlaying")
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                log("onPlaybackStateChanged=${getStateName(playbackState)}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                super.onPlayerError(error)
                log("onPlayerError=${error.stackTraceToString()}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerErrorChanged(error: PlaybackException?) {
                super.onPlayerErrorChanged(error)
                log("onPlayerErrorChanged=${error?.stackTraceToString()}")
            }
        })
        log("start=${getStateName(controller.playbackState)}")
        log("COMMAND_PREPARE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PREPARE)}")
        log("COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM)}")
        log("COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE)}")
    }

    private fun play(url: String) {
        log("play($url)")
        log("before=${getStateName(controller.playbackState)}")
        controller.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
        controller.prepare()
        controller.play()
        log("after=${getStateName(controller.playbackState)}")
    }

    private fun getStateName(i: Int): String? {
        return when (i) {
            1 -> "STATE_IDLE"
            2 -> "STATE_BUFFERING"
            3 -> "STATE_READY"
            4 -> "STATE_ENDED"
            else -> null
        }
    }

    private fun log(message: String) {
        Log.e("=====[TestMedia]=====", message)
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestMedia"
        tools:targetApi="33">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestMedia">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".PlaybackService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService" />
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here's the debug log:

```
01:51:22.004  E  onCreate MainActivity
01:51:22.544  E  start=STATE_IDLE
01:51:22.544  E  COMMAND_PREPARE=true
01:51:22.544  E  COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM=true
01:51:22.544  E  COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE=true
//click 1
01:51:24.027  E  play(https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3)
01:51:24.027  E  before=STATE_IDLE
01:51:24.029  E  onPlaybackStateChanged=STATE_BUFFERING
01:51:24.029  E  after=STATE_BUFFERING
01:51:24.053  E  onPlaybackStateChanged=STATE_ENDED
//click 2
01:51:25.715  E  play(https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3)
01:51:25.715  E  before=STATE_ENDED
01:51:25.716  E  onPlaybackStateChanged=STATE_BUFFERING
01:51:25.716  E  after=STATE_BUFFERING
//click 3
01:51:26.749  E  play(https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3)
01:51:26.749  E  before=STATE_BUFFERING
01:51:26.750  E  after=STATE_BUFFERING
//click 4
01:51:30.172  E  play(https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3)
01:51:30.172  E  before=STATE_BUFFERING
01:51:30.173  E  after=STATE_BUFFERING
```

So it looks as if after the first click the player buffers and then immediately ends, and after the second click it just buffers indefinitely. Anyone got an idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update:

It was fixed in [Version 1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media3#1.1.0).

> Add default implementation to MediaSession.Callback.onAddMediaItems to allow requested MediaItems to be passed onto Player if they have LocalConfiguration (e.g. URI).

---

Old Answer:

Finally I found the solution thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/125) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096715/adding-mediaitem-when-using-the-media3-library-caused-an-error). It seems like the Media3 Guide is missing a very crucial part.

From the onAddMediaItems documentation: `Note that the requested media items don't have a MediaItem.LocalConfiguration (for example, a URI) and need to be updated to make them playable by the underlying Player.`

In the end I solved it by overriding MediaSession.Callback.onAddMediaItems

```
class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService(), MediaSession.Callback {

    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player).setCallback(this).build()
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? =
        mediaSession

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onAddMediaItems(
        mediaSession: MediaSession,
        controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
        mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>
    ): ListenableFuture<MutableList<MediaItem>> {
        val updatedMediaItems = mediaItems.map { it.buildUpon().setUri(it.mediaId).build() }.toMutableList()
        return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
    }
}
```

and then replacing

```
controller.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
```

by

```
val media = MediaItem.Builder().setMediaId(url).build()
controller.setMediaItem(media)
```

Comment: To everyone using this snippet: please notice the `setCallback` in `onCreate`

Comment: You have no idea how much trouble you saved me from. They should've mentioned this sh#t in the documentation as it is the most crucial part to get things to work. Their sample apps are so complicated and overly coded to the point you can't even bother to decipher them line by line, especially for an amateur such as myself. Thank you man !