# Android Media3 Session & Controller - Playback with merging media source

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession

I'm trying to use a media session in my app to make background playback and notifications and all that work. The problem is that the documentation isn't very good and there's missing features. The main feature which was causing me issues is not being able to set media items in the media controller. I found this other post asking about the same problem [Android Media3 Session & Controller - Playback not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035158/android-media3-session-controller-playback-not-starting), and the solution does work. However, that's only for a singular URI. I need to be able to play audio and video at the same time somehow. Can I make it work somehow or am I just doomed to only have a media app that cant play audio?

I would've asked in a comment on the solution, but there's a requirement for 50 rep... which is stupid.